# Positive Operator on $C(X)$ with norm 1

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a compact set, $C(X)$ the space of continuous function with values in $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual norm (uniform convergence) and an operator $T: C(X) \to C(X)$ with these conditions

1- Nonnegative: For every $ f\in C(X)$ such that $f \geq 0$ we have $Tf \geq 0$.

2- Let $1(x)=1$ for every $x \in X$, then $T1=1$

I can prove with these hypothesis that $T$ is a contraction. Indeed, for every $f \in C(X)$
$$||Tf(x)|| \leq ||f||||T(1)|| = ||f||.$$
Is it correct? Because I have a problem (the model which I'm working can't get this property), I can prove that $||T||=1$:
$$1 = \frac{||T1||}{||1||} \leq \sup_{f \in C(X)}\frac{||Tf||}{||f||} = ||T|| \leq 1$$
These calculation are correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your first inequality seems suspicious. On which basis do you get that?

Comment: I use the postivity of the operator: we have $f(x) \leq ||f||1(x)$ for every $x \in X$, then $T(f) \leq T(||f||1)=||f||1$.

Comment: Ahhh. But it could be negative. Better: $-\|f\|\le f\le\|f\|\,\Longrightarrow\,-\|f\|\le Tf\le\|f\|\,\Longrightarrow\,|Tf|\le\|f\|\,\Longrightarrow\,\|Tf\|\le\|f\|$.

Comment: Great! The another calculation is correct? Can I conclude that $||T||=1$?

Comment: Yes, Paul, you can.  Good job.